# How do I show a qr code in SSRS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am in the quest to build a report in ssrs/report builder that contains a qr code, is it possible to achieve this?

I was thinking in implementing a class using c#/vb.net that codes any url/mail address into a QR Code and then import that code into the report to use it.

What would be your advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Generate QR Code® barcodes in an SSRS report with the QRCoder library](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/178461/)

> These are the steps required to create an SSRS report that displays QR
>   code symbols using the QRCoder library:
>
> 1. Obtain existing or compile the two QRCoder assemblies with strong names and the PartiallyTrustedCallers attribute
> 2. Install the two assemblies to the global assembly cache (GAC) using the gacutil.exe utility
> 3. Create a new SSRS report that queries a table of test data
> 4. Add a reference to the QRCoderImageToByteArray GAC assembly
> 5. Add a custom code function that sends a string to the QRCoderImageToByteArray assembly and accepts a byte array in return
> 6. Add a field to the report and increase the physical dimensions of the field to accomodate a larger QR code symbol
> 7. Drag-and-drop an image componenet to the new field to bring up the image properties dialogue
> 8. Change the image source to Database, add a function that references the custom code function and change the MIME type to image/png
> 9. Set the size property of the image component to fill the available field space while maintaining the original aspect ratio
> 10. Execute the report to display the data and the QR code generated from the data

This solution based on [QRCoder](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki).

The main points are to register assemblies in GAC, write code calling these assemblies from the report:
[image: custom report function]

And use that code as source for image component:
[image: using component as image source]

Comment: This good described solution nearly worked for me, only I did not find the QRCoderImageToByteArray assembly in the latest stable QRCode project downloads. So I created a strong named DLL of the QRCoder.Net40 project, loaded it into the GAC, referenced it from the report and customized the report's (VB) code: basically you need to call the CreateQrCode(...) and QRCode(...) methods and store the result in a bitmap, like in the example of the [QRCoder HowTo](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/wiki/How-to-use-QRCoder). If anyone is interested in the whole adjusted code, I will post it.

Comment: Hi Marc - I'm interested in the solution you came up with, I'm doing something similar but used the other project type.  Hitting a few walls calling the convert to byte code, SSRS doesn't want to read the class file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a CodePlex page with an open source C# [QR generator](http://qrcode4cs.codeplex.com/releases/view/74015) that someone has already implemented in SSRS.

(Follow at the link in the Reviews section for the SSRS implementation.)

I'm sure you could create or find a solution that is easier to integrate, but I don't think you have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way is to embed an image into your SSRS report. The URL of the image would be (non working example) http://qrcodegen.com&Params=12345

Clearly you would need to choose a reputable company to link to. We use a free service (not my idea) - but even the pay ones are cheap.

In order for this to work, the report server will need access to the site you opt for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free API that can be used to generate QR code images. To use it in a report, follow these steps:

1. Insert a new image in your report.
2. For the "Select the image source" option, select External.
3. Hit the function button by the Use this image control.
4. Enter a function the returns a URL that looks like this:

https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=https://PutInYourURLHere.com

Answer (score 0):

The same answer can be found here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/generate-qr-code-barcodes-in-an-ssrs-report-with-the-qrcoder-library

But at the bottom is a zip file with qrcoderimagetobytearray.dll
as well as qrcoder.dll. While the NuGet download only has qrcoder.dll.